# About the nilpotency of a subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, compactness, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a compact group. Let $\mathcal N$ be a family of closed normal subgroups of nilpotency class at most $k$. Assume that $\mathcal N$ is closed under finite intersections and  $\bigcap_{N\in\mathcal N}N=\{1\}$. Let $H$ be a closed abelian normal subgroup of $G$. Is $HN$ nilpotent of class at most $k$ for an $N\in\mathcal N$?

(Additional hypothesis: In the problem I worked on, $H$ and all $N$'s are of (Haar) measure zero and $H$ is the connected component of $G$.)

Comment: The second condition about intersection is equivalent to $\bigcap_N N=\{1\}$. The condition $HN/N$ abelian for all $n$ is equivalent to $H$ abelian (since it implies $[H,H]\subset N$ for all $N$).

Comment: A counterexample with $k=1$: let $G$ be Heisenberg over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, $\pi$ the canonical projection onto $\mathbf{Z}_p^2$, $H=\pi^{-1}(\mathbf{Z}_p\times\{0\})$, $L_n=\pi^{-1}(\{0\}\times p^n\mathbf{Z}_p)$, $\mathcal{N}=\{L_n:n\ge 0\}$. Then $H$ is abelian as well as each $L_n$. But for no $n$ $L_nH$ is abelian (=$1$-step-nilpotent).

Comment: @YCor Thank you so much. If we assume that $HN$'s are all, not nilpotent of class at most $k$, then is it correct that all $N\in\mathcal N$, contains an $M\in\mathcal N$ such that $HN/HM$ is not nilpotent of class at most $k$?

Comment: But $HN/HM$ is a quotient of $HN/H$, which itself is a quotient of $N$, hence is $k$-step-nilpotent (= nilpotent of class $\le k$).

Comment: @YCor In my problem $HN$'s are all open. Doesn't this help to prove the question statement?